# Filtrar tabelas a serem mapeadas pelo Doctrine a partir do EntityManager (sem linha de comando)

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine, doctrine-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma funcionalidade na minha aplicação que consiste em mapear e  gerar entidades automaticamente.

O problema é que o usuário pode selecionar as tabelas que deseja mapear, por isso, devo inserir um filtro com o nome das tabelas a serem convertidas. Para fazer isto em linha de comando basta inserir o parâmetro --filter conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database --force --filter='class_name' xml /path_to_app/entities/metadata
```

Porém estou desenvolvendo esta funcionalidade em minha aplicação visando obter o retorno de um possível erro, utilizando a biblioteca do doctrine esctrita em PHP. Por isso estou criando a função abaixo que realiza o mapeamento de todas as tabelas para xml (prefiro neste formato), e posteriormente cria as entidades a partir do mapeamento. Entretanto não sei como filtrar o nome das tabelas que desejo mapear, ou seja, inserir a funcionalidade realizada pelo parâmetro **--filter='class_name'**.

```
public function mapearTabelasValidar() {

        //Inicializa variáveis
        $dirBin = DIR_THIRD_PARTY . 'composer/vendor/bin/';
        $dirEntidades = DIR_MODELS . 'entidades/';
        $dirMetadados = $dirEntidades . 'metadados/';
        $title = 'Modelos gerados com sucesso!';

        try {

            //Inicializa o Doctrine e a configuração do EntityManager
            $doctrine = new Doctrine();
            $em = $doctrine->em;
            $em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl(
                    new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver(
                    $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
                    )
            );

            //Define os metadados 
            $cmf = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
            $cmf->setEntityManager($em);
            $metadata = $cmf;

            /**
             * Exporta os metadados das entidades em format xml
             * 
             * Comando similar:
             * php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database --force xml /var/www/fwsibe/sistema/models/entidades/metadados
             */
            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($metadata);
            //die();
            $cme = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Export\ClassMetadataExporter();
            $exporter = $cme->getExporter('xml', $dirMetadados);
            $exporter->setMetadata($metadata->getAllMetadata());
            $exporter->export();

            /**
             * Gera as entidades a partir do mapeamento XML gerado anteriormente
             * 
             * Comando similar:
             * php doctrine orm:generate:entities --generate-methods=1 --update-entities=1 /var/www/fwsibe/sistema/models/entidades
             */
            $generator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator();
            $generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
            $generator->setRegenerateEntityIfExists(false);
            $generator->generate($metadata->getAllMetadata(), $dirEntidades);

            //Trata a possível exeção
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            mensagemExcecao($exc, "Falha ao mapear tabelas!", true);
        }
    }
```

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

você pode tentar usar a [classe MetadataFilter](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.Console.MetadataFilter.html) conforme [o próprio comando disponível no projeto do Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/ImportMappingDoctrineCommand.php#L109) utiliza, no seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
...
$filter = 'string de entidades filtradas';
$metadata = MetadataFilter::filter($metadata, $filter);
$exporter->setMetadata($metadata);
...
```

não se esqueça de importar a classe usando a diretiva `use`.